# Fisher Information for Geometric Distribution

Tags: statistical-inference, estimation

Find the Cramer-Rao lower bound for unbiased estimators of $\theta$, and then given the approximate distribution of $\hat{\theta}$ as $n$ gets large. This is for a geometric($\theta$) distribution.

I am stuck on calculating the Fisher Information, which is given by $-nE_{\theta}\left(\dfrac{d^{2}}{d\theta^{2}}\log  f(X\mid\theta)\right)$. So far, I have the second derivative of the log likelihood as $\dfrac{-n}{\theta^{2}}+\dfrac{\theta(n-\sum x_{i})}{(1-\theta)^{2}}$. I just need some help finding the expectation of this.

Comment: The expectation has to be taken with respect to probability measure over $X$. Hence, treat everything in your log-likelihood expression as a constant except $X$. For example if $X$ is poissonian with rate parameter $\lambda$, then $E(\theta+X)=\theta+\lambda$. Now apply the same logic to your case

Comment: I forgot to mention that I calculated the expectation to be $-\frac{n}{\theta^{2}}+\frac{\theta n-n/\theta}{(1-\theta)^{2}}$, where the $n/\theta$ in the numerator is the expectation of $n$ iid geometric random variables. It looked a bit messy, so I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: I am not sure about your computations: I add a general answer. Please, have a look at its structure: if you still have problems with the expectation please tell me, ok?

Comment: There is a small error in your algebra.  One of your numerators is $\theta n-n/\theta$.  If I'm not mistaken, it should be $\theta(n-n/\theta)$.  See my answer below. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6):

I think you misscalculate the loglikelihood:

$$L=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-\Theta)^{x_i-1}\Theta =$$
$$=(1-\Theta)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n}\cdot \Theta^n$$
Then you calculate $lnL$
$$lnL=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n)ln(1-\Theta)+nln\Theta$$
$$\frac{\partial lnL}{\partial \Theta}=\frac{n}{\Theta}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n}{1-\Theta}$$

The second derivate is th folowing:
$$\frac{\partial^2lnL}{\partial^2 \Theta}=-\frac{n}{\Theta^2}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n}{(1-\Theta)^2}$$

For the Fisher information you need $$-E\bigg(\frac{\partial^2lnL}{\partial^2 \Theta}\bigg)$$

$$E\bigg(-\frac{n}{\Theta^2}-\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n}{(1-\Theta)^2}\bigg)$$

In this formation the onli variable is in $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$$ all others are constans. $$E(const)=const$$ so you can get the folowing:

$$E\bigg(-\frac{n}{\Theta^2}-\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n}{(1-\Theta)^2}\bigg)=$$
$$\bigg(-\frac{n}{\Theta^2}-\frac{1}{\big(1-\Theta)^2}\big(E(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\big)-n\big)\bigg)=$$

Well known as if $x_i$ is geometrical then $E(x_i)=\frac{1}{\Theta}$

Because all $x_i$ are independent so $E(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)=n \cdot \frac{1}{\Theta}$

So the final formation is:
$$=\bigg(-\frac{n}{\Theta^2}-\frac{1}{\big(1-\Theta)^2}\big(\frac{n}{\Theta}-n\big)\bigg)$$
So Finaly you get the Fisher information:

$$F_{\Theta}=-E\bigg(-\frac{n}{\Theta^2}-\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n}{(1-\Theta)^2}\bigg)=n\big(\frac{1}{\Theta^2}+\frac{1}{(1-\Theta)\Theta}\big)$$

Answer (score 4):

By definition, the Fisher information $F(\theta)$ is equal to the expectation

$$F(\theta)=-\operatorname{E}_{\theta}\left[\left(\frac{\partial \ell(x,\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2\right],$$

where $\theta$ is a parameter to estimate and

$$\ell(x,\theta):=\log p(x,\theta), $$

denoting by $p(x,\theta)$ the probability distribution of the given random variable $X$.

The expectation value $\operatorname{E}_{\theta}$ is taken w.r.t $p(x,\theta)$. In other words

$$F(\theta)=-\int \left(\frac{\partial \log(x,\theta)}{\partial \theta} \right)^2 p(x,\theta)\,dx$$

for a continuous random variable $X$ and similarly for discrete ones. Just use that

$$\operatorname{E}_{\theta}[f(X)]:=\sum_{k}f(k)p(k,\theta),$$ 
with $P_{\theta}(X=k):=p(k,\theta)$.