# Find the Fisher information of geometric distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

The geometric distribution has density function $$f(x;\theta)=\theta(1-\theta)^x,$$

By definition, $I(\theta) = \operatorname{Var}(U)$ where $$U(x;\theta)= \frac{n}{\theta} - \frac{n\bar{x}}{1-\theta},$$ is the score statistic.

But then $$I(\theta)=\operatorname{Var}(\frac{n}{\theta} - \frac{n\bar{x}}{1-\theta})=(\frac{-n}{1-\theta})^2\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{Var}(x)= \frac{n}{(1-\theta)\theta},$$ which is apparently wrong, but I couldn't figure out where.

Comment: Have you looked at this post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441351/fisher-information-for-geometric-distribution?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa Or this post on CV:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88089/how-to-find-the-fisher-information-of-a-function-of-the-mle-of-a-geometric-p-d?

Answer (score 1):

The steps to working out the Fisher information are as follows

- Work out the likelihood. $$L=\prod_{i=1}^n\theta(1-\theta)^{x}=\theta^n(1-\theta)^{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}.$$
- Work out the log-likelihood. $$l=\log(L)=n\log(\theta)+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\log(1-\theta).$$
- Take two partial derivatives with respect to $\theta$. $$\frac{\partial l}{\partial\theta}=\frac{n}{\theta}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{1-\theta},$$ then $$\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial\theta^2}=-\frac{n}{\theta^2}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{(1-\theta)^2}.$$
- Finally, multiply through by $-1$ and take the expectation of this expression. $$F=\frac{n}{\theta^2}+\frac{n/\theta}{(1-\theta)^2}.$$

I'm sure you can simplify this accordingly.